# Selenium Webdriver: How to bypass Google "accept-cookies" dialog box

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a really simple Selenium WebDriver project in Java where I am using FireFox driver.

My goal is to navigate to Google's page (https://www.google.com) and when prompted to accept
Cookies be able to click on the "I agree"-button to just get rid of it and continue the automation process further. But for some reason I just can't get the browser to locate it.

This is the instruction I am using currently:

```
package main;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class SeleniumGoogleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        WebElement acceptButton = driver.findElement
        (By.xpath("/html/body/div/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]"));
        
    
    }
}
```

I don't know why the browser can't locate it and activate/enable that part of the page
with neither *Implicit wait* or *Explicit wait*. *Thread.sleep()* method don't seem to be the
solution either in this case.

The only error message I get when running the application is that of **"Unable to locate the element"**.

[image: A screenshot of where I get stuck]

Is it that you actually can't automate some stuff with Selenium WebDriver or have I misunderstood some important concepts here?

Much grateful for all tips !

Comment: Maybe Google wants you to actively agree to their terms and intentionally constructed their interface to require human interaction.

Comment: But do you mean that it can block the Selenium WebDriver from actually performing its instructions?

Comment: Who knows? It could be something like "not a robot" internally.  Still, that's not a definitive/expert opinion and someone else should probably answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup is located on an iFrame, first you have to switch to the iFrame:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(yourFrame);
```

after you can find the accept button, and click it:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id")).click();
```

Comment: Super thanks! That solved my issue which I was struggling with for some time now. I could only find the iframe by index though since the page source couldn't display any id or name attribute related to it.

Comment: Yw :) That can also work or you can try to find the iFrame using the source attribute maybe something like this: `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//IFrame[startswith(getAttribute("src"),"consent.google.com")"));`

Answer (score 2):

you can handle it by update the cookies "CONSENT" delete the old one because the value is "PENDING" and Add it with the below value.

```
driverManager.driver.manage().deleteCookieNamed ("CONSENT");
driverManager.driver.manage().addCookie(new Cookie("CONSENT","YES+shp.gws-"+LocalDate.now().toString().replace("-","")+"-0-RC2.en+FX+374"));
driverManager.driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Comment: For simplicity, as for today 2022-06-21 it suffices to set the Cookie value to `"YES+"`

Answer (score 1):

I've used the same solution as Jus, but Chrome had 'I agree' button id changed since then

Here how updated solution should look like

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://google.com/xhtml')

time.sleep(2) # seconds until popup appears

try: # 2 different popups
    frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cnsw"]/iframe') #<-locating chrome cookies consent frame 
    driver.switch_to.frame(frame) 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]').click()#<-looking for introAgreeButton button, but seems google has changed its name since and  it only works in old chrome versions.

except NoSuchElementException:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="L2AGLb"]').click() #<- pay attention to new id.
```

In case if this id will expire, I recommend you to inspect element yourself like this:

[Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW75r.png)

Click twice 'Inspect element'

[Locating 'I agree' button's id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnxmW.png)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for the Python version of Ahmed Hammad's snippet of code:

```
driver.delete_cookie("CONSENT")
driver.add_cookie({'name': 'CONSENT', 'value': "YES+shp.gws-"+str(date.today()).replace("-","")+"-0-RC2.en+FX+374"})
driver.refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://google.com/xhtml')

time.sleep(2) # seconds until popup appears

try: # 2 different popups
    frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cnsw"]/iframe')
    driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]').click()

except NoSuchElementException:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="zV9nZe"]').click()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, avoid asking questions that contain only code, you could improve your question by writing a quick summary of what you are trying to do, this will make it easier for users to better understand your question